# Issue: Difference in saving an Apex Class or Visualforce page using "Save" and "Quick Save". Anyone experienced this?

Tags: setup

I opened a visualforce page and its related controller class in Edit mode inside Salesforce UI. I made several changes and used Quick Save to save it. But i never used Save button in that my logged in session. This happened yesterday. Now, today i opened and happened to see all the changes have been rolled back to previous version.

Is there any difference between Quick Save and Save just like hard delete and soft delete?

Please anybody suggest which tag i should use for this question. i added salesforce-crm and i know it is not correct.

Comment: I'd say the setup tag is more appropriate.

Comment: when you make **save** the system submit the code and return the page detail of the class/page, while **Quick save** submit the code and let you to continue editing your class/page

The code is saved if are not present errors. Have you seen which is the last modified date of the class/page? @BaskaranS

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=pages_creating.htm&siteLang=en_US) here does not indicate any difference.

> Click Save to save your changes and return to the Visualforce detail screen, or click Quick Save to save your changes and continue editing your page. Your Visualforce markup must be valid before you can save your page.

One theory might be, if you used the back button at any time, the content of the in page editor may be resent to previous edits and perhaps posted back. This is just theory though I have not tested it.

Generally using the Back or Refresh sometimes can cause problems in web apps as the browsers attempt to repost (though typically you get a prompt for this). If you have not done either of these things, I'm not sure what might have caused this? Another developer editing at the same time perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I would try the scenarios which you mentioned and get back to you.

Comment: I can confirm that *going back in history* can often cause you to view the older version of the code. This has actually saved me more than once after I made a fatal edit. That said, I almost exclusively use something that is far easier to verify saved changes *and* retain history: Force.com IDE and Git.